# Diacritics in python

Tags: python, kivy, diacritics

Can someone please show me how can I write in python with diacritics?

I'm using python and kivy, and I want to display an message in Label: "Bine ati venit!", and it shound be "Bine ați venit"

```
class ScreenWelcome(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenWelcome,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas: Rectangle(source='/home/pi/googleAPI/play/kivy/images/first.png', pos=self.pos, size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        my_box = FloatLayout(size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        my_label = Label(text="[b]**Bine ati venit!**[/b]",font_size='28dp', halign='center', valign='top', color =(0,0,0,1), markup=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried replacing the t with its unicode ? Like this: `u"Bine a\u021Bi venit!"`

Comment: Can you please tell me from where you get these codes? I have also another characters that I want to replace.

Comment: You can just copy paste your character in the google searchbar, and you'll get [many results](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%C8%9B+unicode&oq=%C8%9B&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j0l4.1431j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). There might be a way to do it in python though.

Comment: Found it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't test currently but is it not possible to simple write that character inside the string? If one is on python2 one probably has to put an "u" before the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find these with a  [google search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%C8%9B+unicode), however if you need a python method:

```
'ț'.encode('unicode-escape')
```

Will give you the unicode:

```
 b'\\u021b'
```

Which you can then include in your string.